# MinionPro package conflicts with {esint}

Tags: math-mode, minionpro, esint

I am using `MinionPro` font but it conflicts with `esint` package. The compiler always complains:

```
LaTeX Error: Too many math alphabets used in version normal.
```

Therefore I am forced to use the integral `minionint` provided by the font .

```
\usepackage[footnotefigures, minionint]{MinionPro}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{esint}  %
\usepackage{bm}   
\usepackage{ngerman}     % ngerman: "a "s "o "u
```

So how to solve this issue by not using `esint` to achieve the same `\iint \iiint` integrals that the `esint` package produces.

**Update:**

As `MininoPro` will call `Mnsymbol` package by default, and `Mnsymbol` conflicts with `amssymb` package if `esint` been used. The solution is just commenting on `amssymb`.

Comment: I do not have this problem just loading MinionPro and esint. Probably you load other math alphabets. What's your preamble?

Comment: `\usepackage{amsmath}` and `\usepackage{amssymb}`, is the 
`{amssymb}` not necessary?

Comment: Not only unnecessary, but incompatible. From the `MnSymbol ` documentation: *The MnSymbol package is incompatible with the
amssymb and amsfonts packages. It automatically loads the amsmath and textcomp packages.*  Actually, only 11 symbols from the AMS collection are not avalaible with MnSymbol, and most of them are taken from the text font. As far as I experienced, only `\mapstochar`, `\lhook` and `\rhook` are really missing.

Comment: yeah. Without `amssymb` it does work. As you already mentioned, i think the symbols from `MnSymbol` are enough for a normal report.

Comment: Please, add also a full minimal example (for future readers). By the way, in my opinion, `MnSymbol` is not only enough, but also ugly :P